# Optimal Solution Set To Linear Programs

Tags: combinatorics, linear-programming

I have the following assignment question, and I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Q: Consider the following LP (P): $\max\{{c^Tx:Ax=b, x \geq 0}\}$, where $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix. Prove or disprove the following.

i) Let $D$ be any $m$ by $m$ matrix. Then the following LP has the same set of optimal solutions as (P): $\max\{{c^Tx:DAx=Db, x \geq 0}\}$.

ii) Let $D$ be a non-singular $m$ by $m$ matrix. Then the following LP has the same set of optimal solutions as (P): $\max\{{c^Tx:DAx=Db, x \geq 0}\}$.

iii) Let $y$ by any vector in $R^m$ and $D$ be any $m$ by $m$ matrix. Then the following LP has the same set of optimal solutions as (P): $\max\{{(c^T -y^TA)x + y^Tb:Ax = b, DAx=Db, x \geq 0}\}$.

Sol: So for part i), I have that the statement is false. It's quite easy to construct an LP with a unique optimal solution, and then picking D to be the zero matrix. Thus the resulting LP would be unbounded, as any $x$ would be feasible. So the optimal solution sets are clearly different.

For ii), I believe that the statement is true. I haven't found a way to prove it yet, but I believe that the reason it would be true would be because the feasible solution space to $Ax = b, x \geq 0$ is the same as $Dax = Db$, since $D$ is invertible. So any $x$ satisfying one set of constraints must also satisfy the other (which wasn't the case in part i). Also since there is no change to the objective function, the optimal solution sets are identical.

For iii) I am stuck. Further, I don't really understand the point of introducing the vector $y$, as if $Ax = b$, then $y^TAx = y^Tb$, and so in the objective function $(c^T - y^TA)x + y^Tb$ would be the same as just $c^Tx$. Also, I don't really know where to go from here. I can't seem to construct a counter example, but can't seem to prove it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct for (i).

Let $\Omega_P = \{x | Ax = b, x \ge 0 \}$.

For (ii), let $\Omega_{ii} = \{x | DAx = Db, x \ge 0 \}$. Since $D$ is invertible, we have $Ax=b$ **iff** $Ax-b = 0$ **iff** $D(Ax-b) = 0$ **iff** $DAx = Db$. Hence $\Omega_P = \Omega_{ii}$ and so the problems are equivalent (same cost and same feasible set).

For (iii), let $\Omega_{iii} = \{x | Ax=b, DAx = Db, x \ge 0 \}$. It is clear that $\Omega_{iii} \subset \Omega_P$. If $x \in \Omega_P$, then $Ax=b$ and so $DAx=Db$, hence $x \in \Omega_{iii}$. Hence $\Omega_{iii} = \Omega_P$. If $x \in \Omega_P = \Omega_{iii}$, then $y^T(Ax-b) = 0$ for all $y$, and hence $c^Tx = c^T x-y^T(Ax-b) = c^T(x-y^TA) + y^Tb$. Hence the two problems are equivalent (the cost functions are the same on the same feasible set).

Comment: Thanks! I was on the right track for (ii) and I understand now what you've done for (iii).